# Cursor in EditText field is not visible when it is focused

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have added this EditText field to my program. When I run this program, I have noticed that the cursor will blink very close to the left edge of the text box. I have many more text fields in the same layout. Because of the above mentioned problem, I cant see which text field is focused. So what is the solution?

Here is my code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/lenbox"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:background="#fb7567" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different technique, I don't have an idea if that would be suitable for you or not.

What you can do is, add `android:hint` in the other `EditText` while your focus `EditText` will not show hint, hence giving an idea on where the focus is

Comment: I also tried that one. But I want to see cursor. The cursor is too close to left edge. Since I am a beginner  for both android and stackoverflow, I cant upload screen shot.